# Windows 2012 R2 closesocket() hangs on listening socket

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, iocp

I have a weird situation on a production server.

We have network application written on C++ which serves users requests by TCP written using IOCP.

Two days ago we did an update of Windows 2012 R2 (it installed latest security updates. The previous update was 6 month ago). And after the update when trying to stop the service we see in logs that server **hangs on call to close listening socket**

```
closesocket(session->listen_socket);
```

The schema of stopping the network system is the next:

1. `PostQueuedCompletionStatus(m_completion_port, 0, NULL, NULL);` x
   the number of worker threads
2. Wait all worker threads finish their job
3. `CloseHandle(m_completion_port);`
4. `closesocket(session->accept_socket);`

   `closesocket(session->listen_socket);`

This was working good for the last 4 years, but suddenly after Windows 2012 R2 update the server hangs forever on call `closesocket(session->listen_socket);`

I've alsi tried as a solution to set LINGER option with 0 timeout to make abotive closure, but it didn't help.

All ideas how to fix this or make any additional diagnostics?

Comment: first of all - look stack trace of call `closesocket` - where exactly code hung. are inside call `NtClose` or in another place

Comment: @RbMm   

`ntdll.dll!NtClose()`

`mswsock.dll!SockCloseSocket()`

`mswsock.dll!WSPCloseSocket()`

`ws2_32.dll!closesocket() Unknown`

Comment: this mean hang was in kernel mode driver. even don't know what in this situation do next

Comment: @RbMm Here is what i've found. https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=49308. Looks like windows security update causing this issue. Will try to remove an update and tell you results

Comment: @RbMm Removing **KB4338815** fixed this issue on all our servers. Thanks for help!

Comment: We have experienced this same issue with a sockets based application/service.  Will Microsoft have an update of the update?

Comment: @MSchenkel See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372116/freezing-winsock-application-after-kb4338830-update/51387161#51387161 for Microsoft's patch for the issue

Comment: thank you for cross posting this..  I appreciate it.

Comment: OMFG, we've been dealing with this for months before I had the good sense to use closesocket in google searches.  I hadn't been thinking below the framework (Qt)! Best part is the process eventually dies, but the port remains in use but hidden in the kernel..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was brought by patch from Microsoft **KB4338815**, which caused closesocket tо hang forever on Intel Xeon processors and this was also posted by FileZilla guys in this thread
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=49308