# Freezing Winsock Application after KB4338830 update

Tags: winsock

Our application suddenly keeps on freezing after some time this happens after the **KB4338830** update.
The unfortunately application cannot be restarted nor be closed, I suspect all of this is because the winsock(just ported) I`m using. It is written on vb.net, and the program has something to do with continuous sending and receiving data from other PCs.

Anybody encountered the same issue? solution? or at least how can I prove it is because of the update.

Comment: Possibly related: [Windows 2012 R2 closesocket() hangs on listening socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359861/) after installing the latest Windows updates.

Comment: Thanks! i saw that too from this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362457/tidhttpserver-freezing-when-active-set-to-false-after-windows-update

Comment: I would have mentioned that post too, since it mentions the same KB you did, but you didn't give any specifics about your project setup, so no way to know if you would have understood the issue of that post or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft just released [KB4345424](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345424/improvements-and-fixes-windows-8-1-and-server-2012-r2) to resolve the issue. Info is from [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/07/17/microsoft-fixes-july-2018-updates-for-windows-7-windows-8-1-and-server/).

For those who come from Google - [KB4345459](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4345459/stop-error-0xd1-after-a-race-condition-occurs-in-windows-7-service-pac) for Windows 2008 R2 SP1 and [KB4345424](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345424/improvements-and-fixes-windows-8-1-and-server-2012-r2) for Windows 2012 R2.

[KB4345421](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4345421/windows-10-update-kb4345421) is for Windows 10 Version 1803 and 2016.

Comment: This fixed my problem also. I had a Delphi app using a TIdTCPServer and it would randomly crash on shutdown.